# do not modify `iso14651_t1_common`

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, locale

I am currently overwriting `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` for some personalizations. How can I make sure this file never get updated when I update Linux?

I mean which package I should not update if I do not want to update `iso14651_t1_common`. And, how to add that package to a blacklist so that `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` does not update that package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg -S` will tell you which package provides that file:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common
locales: /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common
```

You could put that package on hold using `sudo apt-mark hold locales`, but that will cause problems; instead, you should divert the file:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common.packaged /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common
```

With this diversion, updates to `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` will be installed as `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common.packaged` instead, and your changes will be preserved. You’ll be able to compare both files to merge changes if necessary.

To remove the diversion:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common
```